# Iterate by increment of parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have Sql query as below example.

```
Select
  number,age
from 
  tbldetails
where 
  month = @Month and year = @Year
union
Select
  number,age
from
  tblcontacts
where
  month = @Month and year = @Year
```

Now I want to get details of above query for past 12 months of `@Month` and `@Year` and then do average on age.

Example `@Month` = Dec and `@Year` = 2015
I want to get age for Jan 2015 to Dec 2015 and then do average .

I want to use this in ssrs report.

Hoping to get some help :)

Answer (score 0):

To filter for the desired date range, I would combine the year and month into one string column and then use that to compare to your converted parameters (minus one year).

```
WHERE CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
   >= CAST((@YEAR - 1) AS VARCHAR(4) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you Hannover Fist - your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @Year int;
Set @Year = '2016'

Declare @Month varchar(10);
Set @Month = '11'

Declare @Date varchar(10);
Set @Date = Cast(@Month as varchar(2))+'-'+'01'+'-'+Cast(@year as varchar(4))

Declare @StartDate varchar(19);
Set @StartDate = Convert(varchar(19),DateAdd(m,-12,@Date),103) -- 103 dd/mm/yy

Declare @EndDate varchar(20);
Set @EndDate = Convert(varchar(20),DateAdd(m,12,@StartDate),103)

Select 
Sum( StCount) as TotalStudents
(

Select Count(Rollnbr) as StCount,..
Where Date between @StartDate and @EndDate

union
Select Count(Rollnbr) as StCount,..
Where Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
)Sql1